# How to make the routes working with CakePHP in a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, routes, cakephp-2.0, subdirectory

I have a little Webpage set up with a little CakePHP Webapp in it.
The CakePHP stuff is in a subdirectory and so I got my .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
  RewriteEngine on 
  RewriteRule ^test/subdirectory$ subdirectory/app/webroot
  RewriteRule ^test/subdirectory/(.*)$ subdirectory/app/webroot/$1
</IfModule>
```

Now navigating to domain.com/subdirectory works, but for my route to login I only get a 404 =(

```
 Router::connect( '/login', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
```

Could you please help me?

//edit: I just tried around a little bit, my other routes like domain.com/controller/action/id don't work either.

Comment: is that .htaccess file in your web root or in Cake's root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Change your debug level to '2'](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html?highlight=debug%20level#Configure%3a%3awrite).  At this debug level, Cake will tell you what you're actually missing instead of giving you a 404.  For bad rewrite rules, it will probably tell you that you're missing a controller and then it will tell you what path it used when it tried to find your controller.  With that info, you should be able to correct your rewrite errors.

Cake is perfectly happy to operate in a subdirectory though, so your simplest option may be to just move your Cake into /test/subdir.

Comment: The debug level is set to '2' but in tmp/logs/error.log nothing new shows up =/

Comment: @udo If debug is set to 2 and you're getting a HTTP404 error, then you're probably getting the error from your webserver and not from Cake, which means your problem is with the url rewriting and not with the Cake routes.

Comment: Yeah, but why does /subdirectory works and the start-page of the App loads but every other routing goes wrong o.O?

Comment: Oh i forgot to add the RewriteBase to one of the three .htaccess files. Thanks @Farray for pointing me to the Rewrite Rules again ^^